# join, union 3 tables in sql

Tags: sql, database

Please, help me to solve my sql problem.
In my DB I have 3 tables as following
[image]

I have wrote a query that display the total refunded and total invoiced and the method has been used to refund or invoice (cash, credit card or checkout) for a specific order.

my query is as following:

```
SELECT Method, SUM(total_invoiced), SUM(total_refunded)
 FROM

(SELECT refunds.method_rf AS Method, 0 AS total_invoiced,
   SUM(refunds.ref_value) AS total_refunded
FROM refunds LEFT JOIN orders ON(refunds.order_id = orders.entity_id)
WHERE (orders.entity_id = 3)
GROUP BY Method
union
SELECT invoices.method_in as Method, SUM(invoices.inv_value) AS 
total_invoiced, 0 AS total_refunded
FROM invoices left JOIN orders ON(invoices.order_id = orders.entity_id)
WHERE (orders.entity_id = 3)
GROUP BY Method)main_table
GROUP BY Method
```

the output is what I expected. Here it is

[image: output]

My question is:
Is there anyway to rewrite my query, in-order to delete my repeated condition which is WHERE (orders.entity_id = 3) and the query will look like this

```
SELECT Method, SUM(total_invoiced), SUM(total_refunded)
 FROM

(SELECT refunds.method_rf AS Method, 0 AS total_invoiced,
   SUM(refunds.ref_value) AS total_refunded
FROM refunds LEFT JOIN orders ON(refunds.order_id = orders.entity_id)
GROUP BY Method
union
SELECT invoices.method_in as Method, SUM(invoices.inv_value) AS 
total_invoiced, 0 AS total_refunded
FROM invoices left JOIN orders ON(invoices.order_id = orders.entity_id)
GROUP BY Method)main_table
"PUT YOUR CONDITION"
GROUP BY Method
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Just add entityid to each query, group by it. The outer select will then be able to filter by it. Though this will be slower

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `union all`.  `union` incurs overhead of removing duplicates.  The following is a little simpler -- you don't need the `orders` table:

```
SELECT Method, SUM(total_invoiced), SUM(total_refunded)
FROM ((SELECT r.method_rf AS Method, 0 AS total_invoiced, SUM(r.ref_value) AS total_refunded
       FROM refunds r
       WHERE r.order_id = 3
       GROUP BY i.Method
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT i.method_in as Method, SUM(i.inv_value) AS total_invoiced, 0 AS total_refunded
       FROM invoices i
       WHERE i.order_id = 3
       GROUP BY i.Method
      )
     ) ir
GROUP BY Method;
```

I would leave the filters in each subquery for performance reasons.  If you only care about one order, then filtering before aggregating is a win performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff for your response.
Actually, I don't care about performance in this specific task.
I need to move where condition outside of sub-queries.
And I need orders table because basic condition for selecting is there (order entity_id)

Comment: @ZainDeeb . . . According to your `JOIN` logic, `entity_id` is the same as `order_id` in the other two tables.

Comment: @ZainDeeb . . . Then you only need `JOIN` if `order_id` could refer to something other than an order.  That seems unlikely, given the name.